# Matplotlib how to change figsize for matshow

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How to change figsize for [matshow()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.matshow) in jupyter notebook?

For example this code change figure size

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                  'two' : [4, 3, 2, 1, 5]})
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.plot(d.one, d.two)
```

But code below doesn't work

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                  'two' : [4, 3, 2, 1, 5]})
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.matshow(d.corr())
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

By default, `plt.matshow()` produces its own figure, so in combination with `plt.figure()` two figures will be created and the one that hosts the matshow plot is not the one that has the figsize set.

There are two options:

1. Use the `fignum` argument

   ```
   plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
   plt.matshow(d.corr(), fignum=1)
   ```
2. Plot the matshow using `matplotlib.axes.Axes.matshow` instead of `pyplot.matshow`.

   ```
   fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
   ax.matshow(d.corr())
   ```

Comment: Great!   
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.matshow(d.corr(), fignum=1)

Comment: More generally, use `Figure.number` to get the figure number, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42323050).

Answer (score 14):

The solutions did not work for me but I found another way:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.matshow(d.corr(), fignum=1, aspect='auto')
```

Answer (score 10):

Improving on the solution by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest,

```
matfig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.matshow(d.corr(), fignum=matfig.number)
```

This way you don't need to keep track of figure numbers.