# Issues with Matplotlib's Spy, Imshow, and Matshow

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, imshow

I have the following simple code using Python's (I'm using Python 3) `matplotlib.pyplot`'s `spy`, `imshow`, and `matshow`.

```
from scipy import rand, floor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Lx=30; Ly=20
p=0.4

r=rand(Lx,Ly) # Generates random numbers across the 2D lattice of size Lx*Ly
A = floor(r+p)

# Using spy 
plt.xlabel('$L_x$'); plt.ylabel('$L_y$')
plt.spy(A, origin='lower')
plt.title("Figure 1")
plt.savefig('fig1.png')

# Using imshow
plt.xlabel('$L_x$'); plt.ylabel('$L_y$')
plt.imshow(r,  cmap='rainbow', origin='lower', extent=[0,Lx,0,Ly])
plt.title("Figure 2")
plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal')
plt.savefig('fig2.png')

# Using matshow
plt.xlabel('$L_x$'); plt.ylabel('$L_y$')
plt.matshow(r,  cmap='rainbow', origin='lower', extent=[0,Lx,0,Ly]) 
plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal')
plt.title("Figure 3")
plt.savefig('fig3.png')


plt.show()

#Issues

# 1) plt.show() doesn't show spy-plot (Figure 1). 
# 2) Axes labels don't pass to matshow-plot (Figure 3).
# 3) spy-plot shows wrong-label ($L_x$ and $L_y$ are interchanged in Figure 2).
# 4) None of the plots set origin at 'lower', i.e. at the bottom-left position.
```

The 4 issues are mentioned in the ending comments of the code. A major one is setting the origin at the extreme bottom-left corner and the placing the captions at the bottom.

Can these be resolved or the limitations be explained?

The output images are attached below.

[image] 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Essentially you're asking for a `pyplot` tutorial here. `pyplot` always works with a current figure and a current axes. So up the line `plt.matshow` everything you do applies to the same axes. `matshow` will create a new figure though, so everything below that line applies to the new figure. To manually create a new figure use `plt.figure()`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Can you explain why imshow does not create a new Figure object ?

Comment: None of the pyplot commands create new figures, except `matshow` (for some historic reason). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021762/matplotlib-how-to-change-figsize-for-matshow/43023727#43023727) as well.

Comment: Yes, `plot.figure()` only creates a display for Spy-plot and hence resolves the issue #1. But for `matshow` it creates an extra blank image. However, other issues remain as it is!

Comment: (1) and (2) are consequences of working with a different figure than expected. Use `plt.figure()` for *each*  new figure you want to have. Read and understand the link I shared above for the matshow issue. (3) Is a consequence of the array definition. You call the first axis of the array `x`, while it should be `y`. (4) When using `extent` you overwrite the `origin` setting. An in-depth explanation is found in [origin and extent in imshow](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html).